# Display full path in title bar of nano editor

Tags: nano

The nano editor by default displays only the filename being edited, but not its full path.
This can be a problem, if I need to edit old vs new versions of files by the same name.

Does anyone know of a way to toggle or change this behaviour to display a full path?
Or is there no way short of figuring out where this happens in the source code and recompiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man nano` say's nothing about files' paths. `/etc/nanorc` nano configuration file also gives no such option. But if you want nano to display filename's full path, use full path during file's opening:

`nano /home/user/test/test.sh` will show it the next way:

[image]

Comment: wow, I'd never spotted that! Thanks! I may make a tiny script / alias which invokes realpath on the argument first.